# Why does Blender export texture coordinates for obj files even though I'm not using a texture?

Tags: mesh, obj

I created a simple monkey mesh in Blender and exported the obj file to load on my C++ application. Upon inspection of the file I see lines like this:

```
vt 0.900583 0.804677
vt 0.899781 0.626257
vt 0.898822 0.786233
vt 0.887842 0.636527
```

Now, as far as I know **vt** denotes texture coordinates, right? If so, shoudn't these be zero since I'm not using a texture at all?

Comment: Well, there already is an answer - but just to make it clear, as you phrased it yourself, you are exporting **coordinates**, not a **texture**. Coordinates then can be used to place a texture in a different software even though there is no texture on the original object. The coordinates come from the UVs, and although you might not have unwrapped the object - the "simple monkey" like all built-in mesh primitives come with already unwrapped UVs by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the object has a UV Map it is exported. Textures and texture coordinates are separate things. If you do not want your object to have a UV map, delete it before exporting:

[image]

Or simply don't export it:

[image]